# angular 1 [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs

i have error in my app:

```
vendor-cms.js:119 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?p0=ProductProvider%20%3C-%20Product%20%3C-%20TrashListCtrl
    at http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:17:417
    at http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:52:240
    at Object.d [as get] (http://gfexxx.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:50:220)
    at http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:52:314
    at d (http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:50:220)
    at e (http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:50:490)
    at Object.instantiate (http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:51:136)
    at http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:92:306
    at http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:661:23742
    at ca (http://123.com/js/dist/vendor-cms.js:85:90) <div ui-view="" class="content ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

i  google but cant realize whats happend here:

```
start = ->
  angular.module('VitalCms.controllers.trash', [])
    .config(['$stateProvider', trashConfig])
    .controller('TrashListCtrl', TrashListCtrl)

trashConfig = ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider
    .state('trash'
      url: '/trash'
      templateUrl: '/cms/partials/trash/index.html'
      controller: 'TrashListCtrl'
      ncyBreadcrumb:
        label: 'Корзина')

class TrashListCtrl
  @$inject: ['$scope', 'Page', 'Form', 'Product', 'News']

  constructor: ($scope, Page, Form, Product, News) ->
    $scope.displayFull = true
    $scope.resources =
      pages:
        model: Page
        list: Page.listDeleted()
      forms:
        model: Form
        list: Form.listDeleted()
      products:
        model: Product
        list: Product.listDeleted()
      news:
        model: News
        list: News.listDeleted()

    $scope.deleteDoc = (resource, doc) ->
      index = $scope.resources[resource].list.indexOf(doc)

      doc.$delete ->
        $scope.resources[resource].list.splice index, 1
        $scope.alerts.push
          msg: ''
          type: 'success'

    $scope.restoreDoc = (resource, doc) ->
      index = $scope.resources[resource].list.indexOf(doc)
      doc.$restore ->
        $scope.resources[resource].list.splice index, 1
        $scope.alerts.push
          msg: ''
          type: 'success'

start()
```

so i have controller and then injecting it, so why is the error there ?
if i go to angular docs they say its unknown provider, but it seems  is defined and spelled correctly. whats going wrong there ?

Comment: Where are bindings for `Page, Form, Product, News` ??

Comment: scope resources, isnt that ? where i can find them ?)

Comment: No, you are injecting them. So you need to bind them to your module. They can be either factory, service, value or constant.

Comment: please tell me the way how i can do that)) or some link maybe

Comment: What do you mean by Page? What will page variable hold?

Comment: some pages which will be shown to delete them ) and the same about other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158922/discussion-between-kaustubh-khare-and-shoopik).

Answer (score 0):

The [error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=ProductProvider%20%3C-%20Product%20%3C-%20TrashListCtrl) already explains the problem in human-readable form. In order for `Product` service to be injected into the controller, it should be defined. And `Product` wasn't defined.